# SharePoint Custom Web Service not working for SSL configuration

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I did developed a custom SharePoint Web Service . It is working fine when using http. But when we configure SSL(https) , it is not working and throwing the below error.

> Request for the permission
>   of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Security.SharePointPermission,
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Security, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bcee11233hj' failed.

Does anyone came accross a similar situation or any ideas on why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem. It was not this particular Web Service which is causing the problem. It is some other Web Service which is overriding the Config file.

Now everything works fine.